# SQL query to extract all WordPress posts with categories

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, posts

I need to extract all posts from my WordPress DB along with the associated categories and not sure how to write this query. I've taken a couple of stabs at it already with no joy and would appreciate the help?

**EDIT: Here's what I have tried already:**

```
SELECT post_title, wpr.object_id, wp_terms.name
FROM wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = 
wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON ID = wpr.object_id
WHERE taxonomy = 'category' 
AND post_type = 'post' 
ORDER by post_title
```

This seems to work but it returns 1,553 where I know I only have 1343 in my DB.

**EDIT:** 
We did the same thing on another SQL query a little while ago and found that it was pulling in the revisions and other post types but thought that this was resolved using post_type = 'post'

**EDIT:**
Upon looking at the number of categories in the DB, I come up with a total number of 216, 6 off the number if you subtract 1553 - 1343 = 216. So I think this total number of 1553 is coming from the wp_terms table which needs to be excluded and only those that are active with published posts should be shown?

**EDIT:**
The other possibility is that each post can have multiple categories, hence the reason for having more posts (1553). So how could I separate each posts into multiple categories?

Many thanks!

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? can you post the structure of the tables you need to query?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have posted? Does it have an error, or not return the results you want?

Comment: I've added a few EDITs to help with my findings if anyone can take a look at it again please?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is the final answer that worked for me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
post_title
, post_content
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Asking Price (US\$)' AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID) AS "Asking Price (US\$)"
,(SELECT group_concat(wp_terms.name separator ', ') 
    FROM wp_terms
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr on wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE taxonomy= 'category' and wp_posts.ID = wpr.object_id
) AS "Categories"
,(SELECT group_concat(wp_terms.name separator ', ') 
    FROM wp_terms
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr on wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE taxonomy= 'post_tag' and wp_posts.ID = wpr.object_id
) AS "Tags"
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY
post_title
, post_content
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the SQL to grab the tags and categories from the database - helped a lot :)

Comment: `AND post_status = 'publish' `

Comment: More like twelve-foot james! I replaced the `Asking Price` line with the following: `(SELECT DISTINCT wpm2.meta_value FROM wp_posts wp INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm ON (wp.ID = wpm.post_id AND wpm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id') INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm2 ON (wpm.meta_value = wpm2.post_id AND wpm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file') WHERE wp.ID = wp_posts.ID) AS "Featured Image"` - which allows inline retrieval of the post's featured image as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Query for fetch post/posts using post user, post category and post_title */
```

```
$query ="SELECT wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.comment_count, wp_users.display_name, wp_terms.name  
                                        FROM wp_posts
                                        JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
                                        JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                                        LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id)
                                        JOIN wp_users ON (wp_posts.post_author = wp_users.ID)
                                        WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN ($bycat)
                                        AND wp_users.ID = $byuser
                                        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
                                        AND (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '$bytitle' OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '$bytitle')
                                        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                                        ORDER BY wp_posts.post_modified DESC";


/*---- FOR DISPLAY RESULT -----*/
$resultfirst = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        
foreach( $resultfirst as $result ){
echo $result->post_title .'
';
echo $result->display_name.'
';
echo $result->name.'
';
echo $result->comment_count.'
';
}
```