# mysql - woocomerce how to fetch products in a category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm writing a web service , I need to fetch all products in a category , I've written this so far :

```
   SELECT *,ID, `post_date` ,  `post_title` ,  `post_content` ,  `guid` FROM  `wp_posts` as post

INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships rs ON rs.object_id = post.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = rs.term_taxonomy_id 


WHERE  `post_type` =  'product'  
AND  `post_status` =  'publish'     
AND rs.term_taxonomy_id =909
```

the code return 3 items but the problem is , i've about 20 products in this category in my website and in the website it shows all these 20 products .

what is wrong with this code? how can I get all products in a category ?
by the way , I'm using woocomrce api either , if I can use it .

Comment: Sample data is required ...

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071035/sql-query-to-extract-all-wordpress-posts-with-categories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all product related to specific category by using below custom query

```
 //your custom category id   
 $cat_ids          =   123;
 $conn          =   new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);

 $get_pro_by_cat   =   'SELECT ID, `post_title` FROM  `wp_posts` as post 
                       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships rs ON rs.object_id = 
                       post.ID WHERE  `post_type` =  "product" AND `post_status` 
                       =  "publish" AND rs.term_taxonomy_id  =' .$cat_ids.' 
                       ORDER BY post_title';

$avail_products = $conn->query($get_pro_by_cat);
```

**NOTE:** Replace your table prefix with **wp_** table prefix in above query 
**wp**_posts.

You can see the demo at this url : http://cadjewelrygallery.com/ .
I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for reply ,I've tested this code, it works fine for some categories but it doesn't work for most of them , is there any other way to do so  ?

Comment: If you are using woocommerce rest api then please see this link https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/blob/master/source/includes/v3/_product-categories.md .