# MySQL query for getting WooCommerce products by category name

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to update products by specific category only.

I am getting correct results by this MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'product'
```

Now, I have 2 types of product categories `1. ABC` and `2. XYZ`
`ABC` has 5 products and `XYZ` has 30000 products.

I just want to update the meta data of products having categoty `ABC`

For that I have written MySQL Query:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value`= ( CASE WHEN `meta_key` = '_stock' THEN '0'
                         WHEN `meta_key` = '_stock_status' THEN 'outofstock'
                         ELSE `meta_value`
                    END)
WHERE post_id NOT IN( '2268', '2298', '2299', '2135' );
```

I do not want to use `NOT IN` because if any category will be added, then this query will be wrong.

How can I check for the product category in this MySQL query?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `post_id` in `wp_postmeta` is the same as `id` in `wp_u8gwgg_posts `?

Comment: Yes. It stores data of `ID` of `wp_posts` in `wp_postmeta`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307171/mysql-woocomerce-how-to-fetch-products-in-a-category/47308105)

Comment: @AjinkyaBawaskar It is not working for me. I have tried that solution. But it is giving null response.

Answer (score 1):

A subquery should do:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
SET    `meta_value`= ( 
       CASE 
              WHEN `meta_key` = '_stock' THEN '0' 
              WHEN `meta_key` = '_stock_status' THEN 'outofstock' 
              ELSE `meta_value` 
       end) 
WHERE  post_id NOT IN 
       ( 
              SELECT id
              from   wp_posts 
              WHERE  post_type = 'product' );
```

Comment: For a `post_type` as `PRODUCT`, it is working without any issues. But as I have mentioned in the question, I want to update the products which have a specific category such as `ABC` mentioned in question. Can you please help me with the same?

Comment: Again, this will not help anyhow. The query that you have mentioned is doing: setting stock 0 and stock status out of stock for products which doesn't have post_type as `product`. And the interesting thing is none of the `post_id` except `post_type = 'product'` will have meta data `_stock` and `_stock_status`