# Set product to never get out of stock in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store and there are basically 2 categories. `1. Diamonds` and `2. Engagement Rings`

The category `Engagement Rings` have only 5 products which are `Variable Products`

I am importing Diamond Category Products from API and they are simple products. There is no any issue in this process. But it has a feature that sets all other products `out of stock` which are not in that API response.

I want to set something like Category `Engagement Ring` product should never get `Out of Stock`.
Is there any possibility I can achieve that?

I know this question can get downvotes as it is not logical enough. But to save time I want to implement this as a temporary fix. and then I am going to make the procedure fully responsible for this kind of stuff.

Comment: If you are the one handling the API stuff, why don't you just do a small piece of code that cycle through the product category products and set them in stock again after the import is complete?

Comment: I was unable to do so. And I have asked a question long back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076886/mysql-query-for-getting-woocommerce-products-by-category-name) but got no answer to that question.

Comment: Because you tried the mysql-way to do that. But actually if you do that with a small piece of code inside a wordpress plugin that become so much easier to make :)

Comment: I want to do it in MySQL way because I have almost 80000 products and while running `wc_get_products()` it is taking 15 to 20 seconds with 31 different parameters. That's why I have implemented a lookup table for WooCommerce product and running MySQL query on tha data.

Comment: Number of product shouldn't be an issue, you can always batch them into smaller pieces. And if your import work, an update batch must work too. 31 different parameters for what? you just need to query all product inside one category, no need for anything else. But hey, that's just a suggestion :D